# How to make a webserver program go multi-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, pthreads

I have a single-threaded web server that accepts `GET` or `HEAD <filename> HTTP/1.0` requests and returns the file data to the client.

I want to make it multi-threaded using `pthread` library.

Specifically, it creates an instance of `request` class for each GET or HEAD requests, pushes it into a **queue**(for FIFO processing, and it should be able to do the same thing with a `priority_queue` instead, optionally).

When it **executes**, it **chooses** `request` classes to be executed, and processes the requests concurrently.

So, there should be one **scheduling thread**, which chooses a request from the ready queue and scheduling it to one of the execution threads, and one **queueing thread**, which is responsible for listening to incoming HTTP requests and inserting them in a ready queue, and finally there are more than two **execution threads** that executing requests.

The big picture I have in mind is this:

```
(This is pseudocode)

int main{

    queue q; //shared variable

    while(true) {

        pthread_t qt, st, et1, et2;

        request rq1, rq2;
        //create, bind, accept socket

        pthread_create(qt, ... , some_queuing_function , queue); //listen and queue the request

        pthread_create(st, ... , some_scheduling_function, queue);  //select a request from the queue, assign it to rq1 and rq2(using a shared variable, increment the index of request to be selected if executing threads are not full?)

        pthread_create(et1, ... , some_executing_function, rq1);

        pthread_create(et2, ... , some_executing_function, rq2);

        pthread_join(...);
        pthread_join(...);
        pthread_join(...);
        pthread_join(...);
    }

}

void * some_scheduling_function() { ... with mutex on queue }
void * some_queuing_function() { ... with mutex on queue }
void * some_executing_function() { ... }
```

This is the first time I am using `pthread`, or any other libraries for multi-threading, so I do not know much about this..

I am not sure if this design would work, since it is too simple.

I am not sure if the partition of the function is correct, if their order is correct, or if the structure is correct.

Especially, after the execution thread assign requests to all execution threads, and all execution threads execute all requests, how do they go back?

Also, are pthread_join functions required for queuing and scheduling at all?

I have been studying this and trying to find out the solution for a week, but this is very confusing.

Please give me some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can merge "scheduling" and "queueing" into one. Anyway, have you considered [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or just [Asio](http://think-async.com/)? It already can do most of managing automatically, and has examples of multi-threaded servers.

Comment: division of "scheduling" and "queuing" is required by the project description. I do not see the necessity of the division either, though.